# MRTG ThreshProgI/O stopped working after start using rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool, mrtg

I was using MRTG system and it was log usage data to .log files. I was use 'ThreshProgI' to get threshold alerts and it was working fine.

I changed the usage logging format to rrdtool and now my system is logging all usage to .rrd files without any issues.

the problem is now it is not sending threshold alerts. I have testing it with low value 'ThreshMaxI' but the 'ThreshProgI' script not get run.

Have anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined a ThreshDir that is writeable by the MRTG process?

To make Thresholds work with MRTG/RRD, you need to have a writeable ThreshDir defined, as well as your ThreshProgI[] and ThreshMaxI[].  If the directory is not defined, or is not writeable, thresholds do not get checked.

EG:

```
ThreshDir: /u01/rrdtool/thresholds
ThreshMaxO[offset]: 5
ThreshProgO[offset]: /usr/local/bin/notify
```

Comment: Thanks Stave! You are right, I figured it out last Friday and got fixed it. Now its working perfectly :)

Comment: Hi Stave, Not sure whether this is related to the problem I had above.   adding ThreshDir fixed my problem but now I notice that ThreshProgI/O works only at first time. It wont work in next 5 minutes. At first run it create a file in the TheshDir. If I delete it later ThreshProgI/O works. Could you help me to fix htis, Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is by design.  The threshprogI/O is only triggered the /first/ time when the threshold is broken, not on subsequent breaks.  That is why when you delete the threshold files it triggers again.